Mockito service dependency null pointer exception
So, let me show my problem. I have Service class:
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final UserMapper userMapper;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository, UserMapper userMapper) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.userMapper = userMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public UserResponse findById(Integer id) {
        return userMapper.toUserResponse(userRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchEntityIdException(EntityTypeMessages.USER_MESSAGE, id)));
    }

Note, that userMapper is mapstruct mapper. And i have test class:
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class UserServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private UserServiceImpl userService;
    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void findById_withValidUserId_returnsUser() {
        Integer userId = 1;
        User expectedUser = User.builder().id(userId).build();
        Mockito.when(userRepository.findById(Mockito.argThat(argument -> (argument != null) && (argument >=1)))).
                thenReturn(Optional.of(expectedUser));
        UserResponse userResponse = userService.findById(userId);

        Assertions.assertNotNull(userResponse);
        Assertions.assertEquals(expectedUser.getId(), userResponse.id());
    }
}

I try to check method findById in UserService, but i got java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.innowise.util.mappers.UserMapper.toUserResponse(com.innowise.domain.User)" because "this.userMapper" is null
In my mind, i expecting, that userMapper real bean autowired properly without it's mocking(I mock only repository, as you can see). But error show that userMapper is null. How to define this mocks properly, because i want to use default userMapper(not mock, becuse i test mappers separately)

Why should it be injected? You aren't creating a mock for it, nor use Spring to bootstrap your test.

And how to load only userMapper from Spring context?

If you really want that use @SpringBootTest however I would advice against it. Instead create both the mock and the UserMapper manually and with that create the UserServiceImpl. This will be a magnitude faster then using @SpringBootTest.

@M.Deinum So, as i anderstood the best solution is just mock both objects userMapper and userRepository as suggests @6006604?

There is no best solution, it depends on what you want to test. If you mock everything you aren't testing anything only  your mocking library.

Is UserMapper a MapStruct mapper?

What I normally do is:
@InjectMocks
private UserServiceImpl userService;
@Mock
private UserRepository userRepository;
@Spy
private UserMapper userMapper = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);

This creates a MapStruct spy around the userMapper, which we don't actually need, but which does trick MapStruct into injecting it into the class under test. This gets everything done with only annotations.
If you don't want that, you can just create the class yourself:
private UserServiceImpl userService;

@Mock
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    UserMapper userMapper = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);
    userService = new UserService(userRepository, userMapper);
}

Now you've taken over responsibility for creating the test instance of UserService yourself, instead of letting Mockito create it for you with @InjectMocks.

You also need to provide a mock for the UserMapper.
Try adding this to your test class:
    @Mock
    private UserMapper userMapper;

You will also need to provide mocked behaviour for the userMapper.toUserResponse code.
Mockito.when(userMapper.toUserResponse...


If this is a MapStruct mapper I think it would be better to use @Spy private UserMapper userMapper = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class); so that the test is using a real mapper.

@6006604 I know that shoud work, but i really want to use default userMapper bean. But if this is not possible, i will use your variant, thanks

@IvanDx of course it's possible to use the real userMapper bean. You can also forgo @InjectMocks and just create the userService yourself by calling its constructor in an @Before method with the mock userRepository and the real userMapper.

@DavidConrad omg, your prev suggestion about Spy private UserMapper userMapper  works for me! Create an answer, i will mark it as solution, best wishes!
